# How to draw a path for user foot steps in MapBox iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, swift, mapbox, mglmapview, mapbox-gl-draw

I am using MapBox API for loading GeoJson data with the file. It's working fine.

But, I have to draw a path for user footsteps, like from user current location, if he walks to somewhere in any direction need to draw a path. I have seen RMShape class for this kind requirement, but, I want to use in following class because I am already loading a number of annotations from geo JSON file in the same map view.

> MGLMapView

Can anyone guide me, how to achieve this requirement.